# I didn't success to create a war file with maven in eclips

Tags: eclipse, maven, war

[When i enter the command 'maven clean package ' this is what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWqUS.png)

Answer (score 1):

When you build a Java project with Maven, a JDK installation has to be available.  You have apparently installed a JRE, not a JDK.  The JRE installation does not have the Java compiler, just the Java runtime.  Go back to where you installed your JRE from, perhaps https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html , and download and install the JDK, not the JRE.

Also, when you post questions on StackOverflow, if the issue you want to describe is shown in text, don't paste a screenshot of the text, paste the text itself, perhaps in the "Code Sample" format ("{}" icon in the editor) or perhaps "Blockquote" (double quote icon in the editor).